# undefined reference to `_endthreadex'

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to build some source code for a game and am getting this error:

```
LINK crawl.exe
contrib/install/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4c56): undefined reference to `_endthreadex'
contrib/install/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4c56): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined     symbol `_endthreadex'
contrib/install/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):sqlite3.c:(.text+0x806d): undefined reference to `_beginthreadex'
contrib/install/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):sqlite3.c:(.text+0x806d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_beginthreadex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:1508: recipe for target 'crawl.exe' failed
    make: *** [crawl.exe] Error 1
```

I am using Cygwin on Windows 8

Comment: Cygwin isn't a compiler.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a library

Comment: This problem is also reported here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/92670 seems like SQLite is not compiled correctly for cygwin

Comment: I managed to build the code by setting the threadsafe macro to 0 in the sqlite3.c file, but unfortunately the program actually asserts that threadsafe has to be 1 in order to run so it crashed immediately. Anything else to do but wait for sqlite or cygwin to get updated?

Comment: I don't know if there is another solution, but both sqlite and Cygwin are open source, so if you can't find another solution and don't want to wait, you could attempt to rebuild/fix it yourself.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/DBD-SQLite/DBD-SQLite/issues/7